# I am trying to alter route in my custon module. But it is already overridden in one of the contrib module

Tags: drupal-8

I tried to altered route it didn't work in my custom module. it is taking the altered path from contributed module. then i tried to extend the routesubscriber.php from extended module but its still didn't work.

I have cleared cache, rebuild routes, and tried to adjust weight for my custom module giving it highest weight. But still didn't work.

If anyone call help with this issue, it will be great help.

this is MyAppsRouteSubscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MyApps\Routing;

use Drupal\MyApps\Entity\ListBuilder\DeveloperAppListBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Drupal\apigee_kickstart_enhancement\Routing\RouteSubscriber;


/**
 * Custom MyAppsRouteSubscriber for MyApps.
 */
class MyAppsRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriber
{

  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
  {
    // Override the controller for the Apigee Kickstart Enhancement.
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $app_entity_type */
    foreach (\Drupal::service('apigee_kickstart.enhancer')->getAppEntityTypes() as $entity_type_id => $app_entity_type) {
      if ($route = $collection->get("entity.$entity_type_id.collection_by_" . str_replace('_app', '', $entity_type_id))) {
        if ($entity_type_id == 'team_app') {
          $route->setDefault('_controller', TeamAppListBuilder::class . '::render');
        } else {
          $route->setDefault('_controller', DeveloperAppListBuilder::class . '::render');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and i have DeveloperAppListBuilder.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MyApps\Entity\ListBuilder;

use Drupal\apigee_edge\Entity\DeveloperAppRouteProvider;
use Drupal\apigee_edge\Entity\ListBuilder\DeveloperAppListBuilderForDeveloper;

/**
 * Renders the Apps list as a list of entity views instead of a table.
 */
class DeveloperAppListBuilder extends DeveloperAppListBuilderForDeveloper
{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render()
  {
     //code here
  }
}
```

Comment: even after trying to clear cache for multiple times, and after rebuilding the routes and truncated the cache tables from backend it didnt work.

Comment: can you show your routing and module code

Comment: (As a rule, don't add information to your posts as a comment: edit your posts.)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your module is following the details outlined in [Naming and placing your Drupal 8 module - Name your module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/naming-and-placing-your-drupal-8-module#s-name-your-module):

> It must contain only lower-case letters and underscores.

The namespace in your details indicates it is using upper camel case instead of snake cases.

Also ensure your route subscriber has a relevant `my_app.services.yml` services YAML file and tag it with `event_subscriber` or it won't be registered:

```
services:
  my_app.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_app\Routing\MyAppsRouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Make sure your module is enabled or it won't be working either. Debug through it to see where it still fails.

Comment: I have added this in my_app.services.yml. But, still didn't work